# What is the actual class (not abstract and not trait) for Map and Set?

Tags: scala, collections, scala-collections

In Scala, map and set literals can be created through, for instance,

```
val m = Map(1->"a")
```

And the type of the reference `m` and the literal are both `Map[Int, String]`.

However, scala documents show that `Map` is actually a trait, with abstract members that need to be implemented in order to instantiate:
[`scala.collection.Map`](http://www.scala-lang.org/api/2.11.8/#scala.collection.Map),
[`scala.collection.immutable.Map`](http://www.scala-lang.org/api/2.11.8/#scala.collection.immutable.Map),
[`scala.collection.mutable.Map`](http://www.scala-lang.org/api/2.11.8/#scala.collection.mutable.Map)

So my question is: what is the actual, concrete class that the literal `Map` is based on? Same question above is applicable to `Set` as well.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You can find the concrete runtime class with `getClass`:

```
scala> println(m.getClass)
class scala.collection.immutable.Map$Map1
```

So it's [`Map1`](http://www.scala-lang.org/api/2.11.8/#scala.collection.immutable.Map$$Map1), a class defined inside the `Map` companion object. But then we try the same thing on a slightly larger map:

```
scala> val m2 = Map(1 -> "a", 2 -> "b")
m2: scala.collection.immutable.Map[Int,String] = Map(1 -> a, 2 -> b)

scala> println(m2.getClass)
class scala.collection.immutable.Map$Map2
```

Which is a different class. Let's try a map with more elements:

```
scala> println((0 to 10).map(i => i -> i.toString).toMap.getClass)
class scala.collection.immutable.HashMap$HashTrieMap
```

Which is yet another class.

In short, the concrete runtime class that you get from `Map(...)` or `toMap` is an implementation detail and the vast majority of the time you shouldn't need to worry about it (but when you do, you can check with `getClass`).

Comment: Very insightful! Thanks a lot for the answer. Do you have a recommendation of books that describe Scala to such details?