# Concrete and abstract Vector classes

Tags: scala, vector, scala-collections

I went trough [scaladoc](https://www.scala-lang.org/api/current/scala/collection/immutable/Vector.html) and found something that I find strange and I cannot explain.
There is the

```
sealed abstract class Vector
```

with its companion `object Vector`. 
Looking through `Vector.scala` it looks like that the following is happening

```
val test: Vector[Int] = Vector(1,2,3)
```

Here I am calling the apply method of the companion object which is using some factory method to create an object that is a subclass of `Vector` and has a concrete implementation. So the real type of test is not `Vector[Int]` but some other subclass.

When I now print the class

```
print(test.getClass())
```

it returns `Vector` which is an abstract class so the object can't be of type `Vector`.

Is there a way to print the actual class of the object? Similar to when I create my own class without an overriding `toString` scala uses the `toString` implementation of `Any(?)` to print out `myClass@memorLocation`.

Comment: @LuisMiguelMejíaSuárez The docs do say it's a sealed abstract class, right? As for printing the class, you could use `test.getClass().getName()`

Comment: @user oh sorry, I just open the docs again on my PC and I see the `sealed abstract class` part _(for some reason o mobile it just said `class`)_. Anyways,after that I opened a **REPL** _(version `2.13.2`)_ and doing `test.getClass.getCanonicalName` returns `scala.collection.immutable.Vector1` which is consistent with your intuition, there are different classes of **Vector**. So, it must be that you are checking against two different versions of the docs and your code, for example in `2.13.2` there was introduced a new version of **Vector**, maybe before it was just a plain class?

Comment: Yeah, for example on `2.12` it was a `final class`: https://www.scala-lang.org/files/archive/api/2.12.10/scala/collection/immutable/Vector.html and effectively, on `2.12` printing the class name gives `scala.collection.immutable.Vector`

Comment: It must be my "REPL". I am using a Metals Worksheet with Scala 2.13.2 and when I enter test.getClass.getCanonicalName I still get vector..

Answer (score 1):

Use `getClass` to get the runtime class of an object. The rest of the answer expands on Luis' comment.

---

Scala 2.13.2 introduced [implementation subclasses](https://github.com/scala/scala/pull/8534/files#diff-59f3462485b74027de4fd5e9febcc81bR347) for `Vector`

> A second major difference lies in the implementation. Whereas the old
>   `Vector` uses a single class for collections of all supported sizes, the
>   new one is split into `Vector0` to `Vector6` for the different dimensions
>   of the main data array. `Vector0` is a singleton object for the empty
>   vector, `Vector1` (used for collections up to size 32) is essentially
>   the same as `ArraySeq`, all higher dimensions are finger trees.

```
/* Contents of Vector.scala in 2.13.2 */

object Vector extends StrictOptimizedSeqFactory[Vector]
sealed abstract class Vector[+A] ...
private sealed abstract class VectorImpl[+A](...) extends Vector[A]
private sealed abstract class BigVector[+A](...) extends VectorImpl[A]
private object Vector0 extends BigVector[Nothing]
private final class Vector1[+A](...) extends VectorImpl[A]
private final class Vector2[+A](...) extends BigVector[A]
private final class Vector3[+A](...) extends BigVector[A]
private final class Vector4[+A](...) extends BigVector[A]
private final class Vector5[+A](...) extends BigVector[A]
private final class Vector6[+A](...) extends BigVector[A]
...
```

which were not present in Scala [2.13.1](https://github.com/scala/scala/blob/3987e83b7cf0af7c8dcb17a08e8a040ccbe9a5e5/src/library/scala/collection/immutable/Vector.scala)

```
/* Contents of Vector.scala in 2.13.1 */

object Vector extends StrictOptimizedSeqFactory[Vector]
final class Vector[+A] ...
...
```

Hence the runtime class of `Vector(1)` in 2.13.2 is `Vector1`

```
Welcome to Scala 2.13.2 (OpenJDK 64-Bit Server VM, Java 1.8.0_202).
Type in expressions for evaluation. Or try :help.

scala> Vector(1).getClass.getCanonicalName
val res0: String = scala.collection.immutable.Vector1
```

whilst the runtime class of `Vector(1)` in 2.13.1 is `Vector`

```
Welcome to Scala 2.13.1 (OpenJDK 64-Bit Server VM, Java 1.8.0_202).
Type in expressions for evaluation. Or try :help.

scala> Vector(1).getClass.getCanonicalName
res0: String = scala.collection.immutable.Vector
```

Conceptually Scala collections differentiate between [concrete collection type and implementation subclasses](https://github.com/scala/scala/blob/2beea8046e3731785a4b6de444b6f8e64a7d0fc2/src/library/scala/collection/Iterable.scala#L43)

```
/** Defines the prefix of this object's `toString` representation.
 *
 * It is recommended to return the name of the concrete collection type, but
 * not implementation subclasses. For example, for `ListMap` this method should
 * return `"ListMap"`, not `"Map"` (the supertype) or `"Node"` (an implementation
 * subclass).
 *
 * The default implementation returns "Iterable". It is overridden for the basic
 * collection kinds "Seq", "IndexedSeq", "LinearSeq", "Buffer", "Set", "Map",
 * "SortedSet", "SortedMap" and "View".
 *
 *  @return  a string representation which starts the result of `toString`
 *           applied to this $coll. By default the string prefix is the
 *           simple name of the collection class $coll.
 */
protected[this] def className: String = stringPrefix
```

For example, we refer to `Vector1` is an implementation subclass whilst `Vector` as a [concrete collection class](https://docs.scala-lang.org/overviews/collections-2.13/concrete-immutable-collection-classes.html) even though `Vector` is technically speaking an abstract class.

We can observe implementation subclasses at play for other collection types as well, for example

```
scala> Set(1).getClass.getCanonicalName
val res1: String = scala.collection.immutable.Set.Set1
```

Implementation subclasses are usually a [private implementation detail](https://stackoverflow.com/a/37381145/5205022):

> the concrete runtime class that you get from `Map(...)` or `toMap` is an
>   implementation detail and the vast majority of the time you shouldn't
>   need to worry about it (but when you do, you can check with `getClass`).